# Docker container staying up and running

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

I have a failure to understand how does the docker container stay up and running. From what I know, if the container doesn't have any active processes it will shut down automatically independent of commands given.

That's the reason I have instructed my `docker-compose.yml` to do this command which keeps it alive:

```
  gateway:
    build: .
    image: me/gateway
    container_name: gateway
    command: tail -F /dev/null <------
    #    restart: always
    ports:
      - "10091:10091"
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/root/logs
      - vendor:/root/vendor
      - .:/root
    env_file:
      - .env
```

While my `Dockerfile` does the following:

```
FROM php:7-fpm-alpine

EXPOSE 10091

WORKDIR /root
COPY . .
COPY src/scripts/generateConfig.sh /usr/local/bin/generateConfig
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/usr/local/bin/generateConfig"]
```

In this scenario the container stays up, and it's all fine. However I would like to run a script once the container starts, so I have added the additional line to the end of my `Dockerfile`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["generateConfig"]
```

After the command is ran, the container automatically stops. There are no errors when I inspect the log, as the script does the job as it is supposed to. Script is responsible for running a Ratchet web socket process indefinitely.

How can I make the script run and simultaneously keep my container running?

Comment: Have you tested the script locally? Does it run forever as you expect? It would be useful if you also provide the script.

Comment: It is tested and it does run forever. It's rather long, but the main part is `$server->loop->addPeriodicTimer(0.1, [$app, 'checkMessages']);` which loops the Ratchet web socket. Running it manually within the running container shows it as being a running process when using `top`.

Comment: @Norgul can you share your script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. Script which was in command to start the web socket process had this line starting it:

```
nohup php ${serviceProcess} >> /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

The solution was not to suppress output by using only:

```
nohup php ${serviceProcess}
```

It works well now

Answer (score 0):

When you start a container it runs the command you defined in `ENTRYPOINT` or in `CMD`.
This command usually starts a process and as long as this process runs in the foreground the container will still run.
If your process is run in the background the container will stop.
Thus, if you are running a script you need to make sure it never ends.
You can simply achieve that by adding such line to the end of your script:

```
tail -f <some log file> # keep listening on your application log file.
```

Alternatively, you can add some while true:

```
while true; sleep 2; done
```

Hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

#### Quick answer

If your docker run command looked like this

```
docker run yourimage
```

change it to this

```
docker run -dt --entrypoint bash yourimage
```

now run `docker ps` and you should see it running.

#### Why wasn't your container staying running?

A Dockerfile contains instructions for building an image. It's common to have an `ENTRYPOINT` instruction (usually toward the end of the Dockerfile) that tells the image what to do when it starts. If that instruction is missing (or if the instruction is performed extremely quickly) the container will start but stop very soon after because it hasn't been told to do any long-running process.

That's why manually providing an instruction to the  `docker run` command (e.g. `entrypoint bash`) will keep the container running - you're effectively saying "open the bash shell and don't do anything else afterward", so the container does that and that's what keeps it running.

Most of the time you probably want to bake the entrypoint instruction into the Dockerfile, and it's usually (but not always) an instruction to start your application server.